# Code giving me an infinite loop in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have some assembly code that's trying to add up all the even numbers in an array. But, I keep getting an infinite loop when I run it and I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
array BYTE 10,11,13,18,21,23,24,17,45
index BYTE 0
sum BYTE 0
arraySize BYTE ?

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
    mov arraySize, LENGTHOF array
    mov eax, 0
    mov esi, 0
    mov al, 0

L1:        ;for loop
    WHYLE:   ;while loop
    cmp esi, ecx
    inc esi
    test array[esi], 1
    jz EVENNUM
    EVENNUM: 
    add al, array[esi]
    jl WHYLE
LOOP L1

mov sum, al

invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What's `jl WHYLE` supposed to achieve? Also `jz EVENNUM` just goes to the next instruction where execution would continue anyway. You likely want `jnz ODDNUM` with `ODDNUM` being before `LOOP L1` and delete the `jl WHYLE`. Why do you even have two nested loops (the for and the while) if your algorithm only has one.

Comment: Did you want to put a conditional jump after `cmp esi, ecx`?

Comment: Also also that `cmp` is useless and due to the `inc esi` the `test array[esi]` will skip the first item (but access past the last one in exchange). Changing to `test [array+esi-1]` could work.

Comment: @Jester Hi, I'm trying to make the IF loop run only when the index is less than the current size of the array.

Comment: The `LOOP` already takes care of that (assuming your array has at least 1 element).

Comment: @Jester, I added the `jz EVENNUM` because I only want to add to the AL(sum) when the number is even. Could you explain why you suggested using `jnz ODDNUM`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your array always has at least one element, the following can work:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
array BYTE 10,11,13,18,21,23,24,17,45
sum BYTE 0

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
    mov esi, -1
    mov al, 0

L1:        ;for loop
    inc esi
    test array[esi], 1
    jnz ODDNUM
    add al, array[esi]
ODDNUM:
    loop L1

    mov sum, al

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much sense now that I'm looking at it!

Comment: You could start with ESI=0 if you put `inc` right before `loop L1`, after the loads.